# ExecuteScalar doesn't return the first column of the first row

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have this module

```
   strSQL = "Insert Into TblInsurancePersonel (CompId,PersonelNo,FirstName,LastName) ";
   strSQL = strSQL + " Values (@CompId,@PersonelNo,@FirstName,@LastName)";
   using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(AppConfiguration.ConnectionStringName))
   {
      Helpers helpers = new Helpers();
      myConnection.ConnectionString = helpers.GetConnectionString(myUser.ServerName, myConnection.ConnectionString);
      using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, myConnection))
      {
          myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompId", insurPersonel.CompId);
          myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonelNo", insurPersonel.PersonelNo);             
          myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", insurPersonel.FirstName);
          myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", insurPersonel.LastName);
          myConnection.Open();
          int i= Convert.ToInt32(myCommand.ExecuteScalar());
                myConnection.Close();
```

the fields in TblInsurancePersonel  are "Id,CompId,PersonelNo,FirstName,LastName" ,which Id is an Identity, so I want to have its value whenever I a new record is added ( I mean I could have the identity of a new record ) . but it returns the value 0 all the time but the record is added correctly

where is the problem ?

Comment: btw; you can use a "verbatim string literal" to make your query clearer; [like this](http://pastie.org/9506208)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`INSERT` does not return any data; it does not present a first column of a first row... for that, you need `SELECT`.

Perhaps you want:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

after the `INSERT`. There is also an `OUTPUT` syntax that can do this:

```
INSERT ...
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id
VALUES ...
```

Comment: +1 For `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to work, you will need an identity column in the table you are inserting

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I was already editing that in - I had to look up where it comes in the query (I get it wrong every time)

Comment: @Leo which is pretty clearly the case in the question

Comment: uufff, true. I didn't even read the rest of the question. But, it's still worth mentioning for future references

Answer (score 2):

Use `ExecuteNonQuery` and you get the number of affected rows.

```
int i= myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**Edit**:

> ExecuteScalar doesn't return the first column of the first row

Perhaps you want to retrieve the new primary key.

You can use `ExecuteScalar` even for insert-queries but you have to append a `SELECT`-statement. That is useful for example if you want to select the newly created identity value.

For example:

```
string sql = @"Insert Into TblInsurancePersonel (CompId,PersonelNo,FirstName,LastName)
               Values (@CompId,@PersonelNo,@FirstName,@LastName);
               SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
// ...
int newIdentity = Convert.ToInt32(myCommand.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of affected rows , not the first column of the first row, which ExecuteScalar does that

Comment: @nnmmss: do you want to get the new identity value of your PK? I have edited my answer.